# Subscript Dictionary with String-based Enums in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary, enums, swift-extensions

I want to extend `Dictionary` with `String` keys (JSON dictionaries) to allow subscripting with any `enum` that has a `RawValue` type of `String`. The end goal would be multiple `enums` that can be used to subscript JSON dictionaries.

```
enum JSONKey: String {
    case one, two, three
}

enum OtherJSONKey: String {
    case a, b, c
}

if let one = jsonDictionary[.one] { /* ... */ }
if let b = jsonDictionary[.b] { /* ... */ }
```

But I can't figure out how to implement this. I know I need to extend `Dictionary`, but can't figure out either the generic extension constraints or method extension constraints.

My first idea was to try to add a generic constraint to the subscript method. I don't think that subscript methods allow generics, though.

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript<T: RawRepresentable>(key: T) -> Value? { /* ... */ }
}
```

Even if putting generic constraints on a subscript worked, I still need a way to nest my generic constraints. Or to constrain the dictionary to keys that are string-based enums. To put it in code that isn't valid, I want to do this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value { /* ... */ }
}

// or

extension Dictionary {
    subscript<T: RawRepresentable where RawValue == String>(key: T) -> Value { /* ... */ }
}
```

Is extending `Dictionary` to accept string-based enums as a subscript actually possible?

My other thoughts on how to implement something like this included `enum` inheritance and creating a protocol for particular `enums` that I want to use as subscripts. I know some of this can't be done, but figured it was worth mentioning the idea. So, again, to put it in code that isn't valid:

```
enum JSONKey: String {}
enum NumbersJSONKey: JSONKey {
    case one, two, three
}
enum LettersJSONKey: JSONKey {
    case a, b, c
}

// or

protocol JSONKeys {}
enum NumbersJSONKey: JSONKey {
    case one, two, three
}
enum LettersJSONKey: JSONKey {
    case a, b, c
}

// then subscript with
if let one = json[.one] { /* ... */ }
```

**Update:**

I have played with this some more and gotten a little closer. The extension below compiles, but gives me a "subscript is ambiguous" error if I actually try to use it.

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == (key: String, value: AnyObject) {

    // Compiles but can't be used because of ambiguous subscript.
    subscript(key: CustomStringConvertible) -> AnyObject? {
        guard let i = index(where: { $0.key == key.description }) else { return nil }
        return self[i].value
    }

}
```

@titaniumdecoy's answer works so it will be the accepted answer unless someone can come up with something better.

Comment: In a `[String:String]` dictionary, you won't be able to subscript it with `.one`. You'd have to use `JSONKey.one` to do it (in addition to the extension you're asking about).

Comment: That is still fine. That allows a namespace for JSON keys instead of typing `json["someKey"]` or keeping a bunch of `String` constants around.

Comment: Figured it out. Check out my answer.

Comment: While I don't think it helps solve your problem, you can combine multiple where clauses with commas: `where Key: RawRepresentable, Key.RawValue == String`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand it, you want an extension on any Dictionary with String keys to allow subscripting using an enum with String as its RawValue type.  If so, the following should work for you:

```
enum JSONKey: String {
    case one, two, three
}

class JSONObject { }

extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible {
    subscript(jsonKey: JSONKey) -> Value? {
        get {
            return self[jsonKey.rawValue as! Key]
        }
        set {
            self[jsonKey.rawValue as! Key] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var jsonDict: [String: AnyObject] = [:]    

jsonDict[JSONKey.one] = JSONObject()
jsonDict["two"] = JSONObject()

print(jsonDict["one"]!)
print(jsonDict[JSONKey.two]!)
```

---

If you want to extend this to work for *any* enum with String as its RawValue type, you need generics.  As Swift does not support generic subscripts (see [SR-115](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-115)), get/set methods or a property would be required:

```
enum AnotherEnum: String {
    case anotherCase
}

extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible {
    func getValue<T: RawRepresentable where T.RawValue == String>(forKey key: T) -> Value? {
        return self[key.rawValue as! Key]
    }
    mutating func setValue<T: RawRepresentable where T.RawValue == String>(value: Value, forKey key: T) {
        self[key.rawValue as! Key] = value
    }
}

jsonDict.setValue(JSONObject(), forKey: AnotherEnum.anotherCase)
print(jsonDict.getValue(forKey: AnotherEnum.anotherCase)!)
```

Comment: Good answer. Fyi, in the setter you don't need to pass it `value`. The `newValue` keyword covers this (as seen in my answer).

Answer (score 16):

With Swift 4's support for [Generic Subscripts](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0148-generic-subscripts.md) you can now do this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    subscript<Index: RawRepresentable>(index: Index) -> Value? where Index.RawValue == String {
        get {
            return self[index.rawValue as! Key]
        }

        set {
            self[index.rawValue as! Key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows you to use *any* Enum which has String as it's `RawValue` type:

`let value = jsonDict[JSONKey.one]`

This will now work for any String Enum, not just `JSONKey`

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but I seem to be missing a step in my implementation, though. When I use your Dictionary extension above, then declare an enum of String Keys like:    
enum Keys: String {
        case daily = "daily"
        case currently = "currently"
        case temperature = "temperature"
        case summary = "summary"
    }

then try to use it in code like:
let temperature = json[Keys.currently][Keys.temperature].double
I'm getting flagged with an error: "Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'WeatherDetail.Keys'".

Comment: @Gallaugher `Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON'`. The problem there is `JSON`. The subscript is defined for the type `Dictionary`. If you want an example of this solution in use, see here: https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCalendar/blob/master/Sources/iCalendar/Event.swift

Comment: @mluisbrown `dic[JSONKey.one] = JSONKey.two` this will still cause the dictionary value to store the enum and not the rawValue.

Answer (score 3):

So this worked for me:

```
enum JSONKey: String {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

extension Dictionary {
    subscript(key: JSONKey) -> Value {
        get {
            let k = key.rawValue as! Key
            return self[k]!
        }
        set {
            let k = key.rawValue as! Key
            self[k] = newValue
        }
    }

}

var jsonDictionary = [JSONKey.one.rawValue : "hello", JSONKey.two.rawValue : "hi there", JSONKey.three.rawValue : "foobar", "fourth value" : 4]

let one = jsonDictionary[.one]
let two = jsonDictionary[.two]
var three = jsonDictionary[.three]
let four = jsonDictionary["fourth value"]

jsonDictionary[.three] = 5
three = jsonDictionary[.three]

print("One: \(one), Two: \(two), Three: \(three), Four: \(four!)")
```

And it prints:

```
"One: hello, Two: hi there, Three: 5, Four: 4\n"
```